# Primereact - Автозаполнение шаблона для issue(Проблема)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hook, primefaces

Мне нужно решение для проблемы, которую я не могу решить.

https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/autocomplete/

Есть библиотека primereact, там есть элемент автозаполнения. У неё есть возможность индентификации `itemTemplate` (пункт в списке) и `selectedItemTemplate` (когда конкретный пункт выбран). Но я не могу реализовать отображение такого шаблона когда страница загружается с режиима редактирования.

Как оно выгллядит:

[image: This is a list template and it works]

[image: The selected template also works]

[image: When reloading the form, we only get the id in the field, which is the knowledge of the 'field' parameter of the autocomplete component.]

Как оно выглядит в коде:
`React - Redux - React hook form - Primereact`

```
<Controller
              control={control}
              name="client_id"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <AutoComplete
                  {...field}
                  type="text"
                  suggestions={channelList}
                  completeMethod={getChannels}
                  dropdown
                  // field="id"
                  field="id"
                  selectedItemTemplate={(item) => {
                    return `#${item.id} ${item.email}`;
                  }}
                  itemTemplate={(item) => {
                    return `#${item.id} ${item.email}`;
                  }}
                />
              )}
            />
```

Где:

`{...field}` - стандартный react-hook-form методы

`suggestions` - массив объектов

'completeMethod' - запрос функции авто завершения

`field:string` - Поле где ты получишь своё состояние после выделения.

Вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы когда форма загрузилась в поле значения, оно бы выглядело так как в шаблоне?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.